# How do I set the pose of an object in pydrake manually after creation?

Tags: python, drake

I would like to create an object in pydrake that is loaded from a URDF (e.g. just a single-link URDF that has an object mesh), and be able to manually set the pose of the object as I wish after creation. What I've been doing so far is this:

```
urdf = FindResourceOrThrow(my_urdf_path)
parser.AddModelFromFile(urdf)
frame = plant.GetFrameByName("my_frame")
T = RigidTransform(p=pos, rpy=RollPitchYaw(rpy))
plant.WeldFrames(plant.world_frame(), frame, T)
```

That lets me set the pose on creation. However, I don't know how to change the pose once the plant has been finalized. I assume there's a way to do this but am struggling to find an example. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do it as follows:
(1) Attach a FixedOffsetFrame (e.g., "robot_base") to the world.  The offset is a *parameter* of the context, not State dofs.
(2) Weld the robot to robot_base.
(3) Re-pose that frame in a Context.

---

(1) goes like:

```
robot_base = plant.AddFrame(frame=FixedOffsetFrame(
    name="robot_base",
    P=plant.world_frame(),
    X_PF=RigidTransform_[float].Identity(),
    model_instance=None))
```

(3) goes like:

```
robot_base.SetPoseInBodyFrame(context=context, X_PF=new_pose)
```

(Yes, Drake's examples should show this better; it's a bit obscure right now.)

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you're looking for is SetFreeBodyPose ([C++](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html#a11f73bcbe2af96a9f46479536f2ad3ab), [Python](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.multibody.plant.html#pydrake.multibody.plant.MultibodyPlant_.MultibodyPlant_%5Bfloat%5D.SetFreeBodyPose)). Do this *instead* of welding your frame to the world frame.

It's worth nothing that you need to do with a `Context`.  I.e., something like:

```
urdf = FindResourceOrThrow(my_urdf_path)
parser.AddModelFromFile(urdf)
plant.Finalize()
body = plant.GetBodyByName("my_body")
T = RigidTransform(p=pos, rpy=RollPitchYaw(rpy))
context = plant.CreateDefaultContext()
plant.SetFreeBodyPose(context=context, body=body, X_WB=T)
```

(Note the change from grabbing the *frame* to the *body*. I assume the frame you grabbed is the body frame of a body.)

Comment: Thank you, I think that is exactly what I'm looking for. However, I also have a robot in the scene (using again `parser.AddModelFromFile`), and one side-effect is now my inverse kinematics problem is also trying to solve for the pose of the free body - i.e. for my 7-DOF arm the decision variable is now 7 joint positions and a position/quaternion pose. Is there a way to manage the free body poses separately from my robot? Should I have a separate plant for the free bodies?